# JQuery Hover: dynamically changing image when hover over project title

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, frontend

```js
jQuery(
  function ($) {
    let title;
    let image; 
    $( "#project-link #project-title" ).on(
        'mouseenter',
        function(){
            title = $( this ).data( 'controls' );
            image = $( ".featured-image").data('w-id');
            $( title + image ).animate( {"opacity": "1"}, "slow" );
            console.log(image)
        }
    ).on(
        'mouseout',
        function() {
            title = $( this ).data( 'controls' );
            image = $( ".featured-image").data('w-id');
            $( title + image).animate( {"opacity": "0"}, "slow" );
        }
    )
});
```

```css
#featured-image{
    position: relative;
    .featured-image{
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

}
```

```html
//FEATURED IMAGE in an ACF field. 
'<div id="featured-image">';
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    if ( function_exists( 'get_field' ) ) {
      $images = get_field( 'project_featured_photo' );
      if ( $images ) {
        echo '<div class="featured-image" data-w-id="#' . esc_attr( get_the_title() ) . '">';
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $images, 'fullsize');
        echo '</div>';
      }
    }
  }
'</div>';

//CUSTOM POST, PROJECT TITLE
if ( get_field( 'project_title' ) ) :
echo '<a id="project-link" href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">';

echo '<h3 id="project-title" data-controls="#' . esc_attr( get_the_title() ) . '">' . esc_attr( get_the_title() ) . '</h3>';
echo '</a>';
endif;
```

Building this is for my WordPress portfolio. I have been trying dynamically change images when hovering over the project title. I have put a project ACF field for the title and images.

The problem with this is when I hover over the project title, all the featured images show up.

This is as far as I got. I have been at this a whole week. I don't know what knowledge I am missing. Any help is appreciated!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#project-link #project-title").hover(
      function(){
        $("#featured-image DIV").stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
      }, 

      function(){
        $("#featured-image DIV").stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
      }
    )
  
  });
```

```css
#featured-image{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;

    
    div{
        opacity: 0;
    }

}
```

```html
<?php//images
echo '<div id="featured-image">';
        while ($query-> have_posts()) {
        $query -> the_post();
        if(function_exists('get_field')){
          $images = get_field('project_featured_photo');
          if($images){
              echo '<div id="';
              the_title();
              echo '">';
              echo wp_get_attachment_image($images, 'fullsize');
              echo '</div>';
          }

        }                       
      }
echo '</div>';?>

<?php //project titles

if(get_field('project_title')):
      echo '<a id="project-link" href='.get_permalink().'>';
      echo '<h3 id="project-title">';
      the_title();
      echo '</h3>';
      echo'</a>';
endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery isn't specific enough to do what you want.  You want to specify which images get triggered.  What you have now will definitely cause all to show.  Also, your PHP code can be optimized a bit.  Without having your custom fields, it can't really be tested, but this should work.

Try this:

```
jQuery(
    function ($) {
        let title;
        $( "#project-link #project-title" ).on(
            'mouseenter',
            function(){
                title = $( this ).data( 'controls' );
                $( title + "img" ).animate( {"opacity": "1"}, "slow" );
            }
        ).on(
            'mouseout',
            function() {
                title = $( this ).data( 'controls' );
                $( title + "img" ).animate( {"opacity": "0"}, "slow" );
            }
        )

    }
);
```

and for the PHP

```
<?php
// images.
echo '<div id="featured-image">';
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    if ( function_exists( 'get_field' ) ) {
        $images = get_field( 'project_featured_photo' );
        if ( $images ) {
            echo '<div id="' . esc_attr( get_the_title() ) . '">';
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $images, 'fullsize' );
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}
echo '</div>';
?>

<?php
// project titles.

if ( get_field( 'project_title' ) ) :
    echo '<a id="project-link" href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">';
    echo '<h3 id="project-title" data-controls="#' . esc_attr( get_the_title() ) . '">' . esc_attr( get_the_title() ) . '</h3>';
    echo '</a>';
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Hello, I couldn't get it to work. I tried console.log the following object $(title + 'IMG') and this is what I got back in the chrome console. This is the same reply I got from hovering three different project titles. s.fn.init [prevObject: S.fn.init(1)]
length: 0
prevObject: S.fn.init(1)
0: document
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Object(0)
[[Prototype]]: Object(0)

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot your extremely specific issues with general advice.  I would check to see what the rendered HTML is with respect to your `<h3 id="project-title">` which if there are multiples, then using the same ID multiple times is a bad practice.  Also, check that `data-controls` actually renders something that matches the `featured-image` element ID.